# Check if user is logged out

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When you have a short lived user access token and the user logs out of Facebook, trying to use that token will result in an error telling you that the user has logged out. When you have a long lived token, it doesn't matter if the user logged out, the token is valid until it expires in ~60 days. Is there a way to see if a user has logged out of FB using a long lived token?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: That uses an xhr call to an endpoint that is not documented and also blocked when you have 3rd party cookies disabled.

Comment: Well this is something internal, you are not supposed to communicate with that endpoint directly - but to use the provided SDK method. _“also blocked when you have 3rd party cookies disabled”_ - and? I am not sure what actual _problem_ you are trying to solve here, so please explain.

Comment: It's pretty simple, when user is logged into Facebook and my app, I need to detect it when 3rd party cookies are disabled. You can notice that the Continue as button does not work when 3rd party cookies are disabled or in a privacy focused browser. I need a way to show that button in all browsers and the only way I can think of is detecting it somehow with long lived tokens.

Comment: I don’t see how long-lived tokens would be able to help with that. To avoid the 3rd-party cookies blocked problems as much as possible, you should perhaps switch to the server-side login flow then?

Comment: The login flow using a popup works great. Ideally what I need is when the user returns back to the site, logged out but still logged into FB, to detect it server side and have a manually built Continue As button display, as the auto one from FB gets blocked.

Comment: Well that could at most be “Continue as … unknown” then, because there is no way you will get a user name or profile picture in that situation. And detecting that the user is still logged into Facebook, purely on the server-side - also impossible, I would think, because without the _client_ communicating with facebook.com, you got no access to any relevant cookies from their domain either.

Comment: Short lived tokens tell you if a user is logged in or not. So you can do it server side, long lived tokens or the other hand, that is the problem and hence my question.

Comment: _“So you can do it server side”_ - well, yeah, _if_ you got a short lived token, and can determine that from how it behaves. But if you don’t have one, then you can not. The long lived token does not give you that kind of information, as you have already discovered - so the _only_ way to check in that situation then, is to communicate with Facebook.